# Using parcelable pass data got java.lang.ClassCastException after clearing ram

Tags: android, ram, classcastexception, parcelable

I implements two classes to the Serializable and Parcelable.

The data class like this,the details of Serializable and Parcelable are nomitted.

```
public class Test1 implements Parcelable  {

public Test1() {
}

String s1;
String s2;
String s3;
String s4;
String s5;
String s6;

}

public class Test2 implements 
Serializable  {

public Test2() {
}

String s1;
String s2;
String s3;
String s4;
String s5;
String s6;

}
```

and write two class to extend they like this

```
public class test11<T> extends test1{

private List<T> list;

public test11(List<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
}


public List<T> getList() {
    return list;
}
 }

public class test22<T> extends test2{

private List<T> list;

public TextSSS2(List<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
}


public List<T> getList() {
    return list;
}
}
```

and I put the data in bundle pass to fragment

```
            Test1 test1 = new Test1();
            test1.setS1("1");

            List<Test1> list1 = new ArrayList<Test1>();
            list1.add(test1);
            Test11 test11 = new Test11(list1);


            Test2 test2 = new Test2();
            test2.setS1("2");


            List<Test2> list2 = new ArrayList<Test2>();
            list2.add(test2);
            Test22 test22 = new Test22(list2);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("test1", test11);
            bundle.putSerializable("test2", test22);

            Fragment fragment = new TestFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.containerF, fragment, "AAA")
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

and get the data in fragment

```
        Test11 test11 = getArguments().getParcelable("test1");
        Test22 test22 = (Test22) getArguments().getSerializable("test2");

        L.e("1", test11.toString());
        L.e("2", test22.toString());
```

it works fine when the app is in normal use.but after I clear the ram and go back to the app, it is crashed by ClassCastException!

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: test2018.my.mynewtest.Test1 cannot be cast to test2018.my.mynewtest.Test11
    at test2018.my.mynewtest.TestFragment.updateData(TestFragment.java:53)
    at test2018.my.mynewtest.TestFragment.onCreateView(TestFragment.java:42)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6959)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
```

The crashed line at

```
 Test11 test11 = getArguments().getParcelable("test1");
```

I want to know how it was caused.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how to [implement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) Parcelable. There are some things missing like the

> non-null static field called CREATOR

And you can't implement Parcelable on a super type. It has to be done for each class.

Comment: But it works fine when the app is in normal use, I feel strange!